# Trying to print post date in Jekyll fails with undefined method `strftime'

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I've been using [Liquid extensions](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/liquid-extensions) to reformat dates on my Jekyll based site, for example:

```
<p>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</p>
```

This works fine in my `index.html` page which just takes the five most recent posts and then iterates them post by post. However, this fails when I am trying to render such a date within my `_layouts/base.html` template.

I have tried:

```
{{ page.date | date_to_string }}
```

`{{ page.title }}` works without issue, and `{{ page.date}}` renders when I use it without the liquid filter, outputting, for example, `2012-03-12 00:00:00 +0000`.

Why does the `date_to_string` filter fail with the input provided by `{{ page.date }}`. I get the following error:

```
Liquid Exception: undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass in base
```

And the build fails. Thanks for any help!

Comment: nice question, lots of people use Tom's template now meet this problem https://github.com/mojombo/tpw/blob/master/_layouts/post.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On my site I use

```
{{ page.date | date: "%d %B %Y" }}
```

It grabs the date from the markdown file. And is rendered like so:

`26 December 2012`

See these links for some extra reading:

[How does Jekyll date formatting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395520/jekyll-date-format)

http://liquid.rubyforge.org/classes/Liquid/StandardFilters.html#M000012

EDIT: To answer your question in the comments section:

If you want to use date_to_string you have to call it like this:

```
{{ site.time | date_to_string }}
```

There is also `{{ site.time | date_to_long_string }` which will write the month out in it's full form eg. November not Nov.

Source

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Liquid-Extensions

Comment: As per the second answer to your linked, date_to_string is part of the standard filters that Jekyll adds to liquid. It works on GH Pages, which probably means its related to a Ruby/Jekyll/Liquid version mixup, just wondered whether anyone had pointers regarding that?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to a string? why not just generate it using the way I have done on my site?

Comment: Essentially, it does exactly the same as ```| date "%d %b %Y"```, I was just interested by the fact that it doesn't appear to work given some combinations of Jekyll and Ruby, which seems odd!