# Using liquid tags in YAML Front Matter variables

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

Is it possible to use Liquid tags in YAML Front Matter variables?

For example if test.html contains:

```
---
variable: "Date: {% date: '%D' %}"
---
{{ page.variable }}
```

then Jekyll will generate the following HTML:

```
Date: {% date: '%D' %}
```

instead of something like:

```
Date: 03/13/14
```

Basically I'd like the Liquid tags in the YAML Front Matter variables to be processed.

Comment: have you been able to solve this? I am stuck here too.

Comment: No, I had to restructure my pages to avoid liquid tags in the Front Matter variables. It seems to me that this limitation can not be worked around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include jekyll / liquid template data in a YAML variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487110/include-jekyll-liquid-template-data-in-a-yaml-variable)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to store a formatted date in a variable so you don't need to re-format the date each time you use it.

Rather than filtering the date in the front matter you could just add a Liquid capture statement just below the front matter.  This will allow you assign your formatted date to a variable so you can use it in expressions.

```
---
title: Some sweet title
layout: default
date: 2014-9-17 # Could come from post's filename, but I put it here explicitly
---
{% capture formatted_date %}{{ page.date | date: "%-d %B %Y" }}{% endcapture %}
```

Once you have your new formatted date variable you can use it as an expression anywhere:

`{{ formatted_date }}` outputs: `17 September 2014`

[More on formatting the date itself.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395520/how-does-jekyll-date-formatting-work)

Comment: Will this work for overwriting the existing variables? I would like my `title` to be `Updated list as of $YEAR` and have that go into all the places where `title` would go.