# Jekyll - Get the date of the last post

Tags: jekyll

I know that i can get the post date with `post.date`.

But, how i can get the date of the last post or the date related with the last time the website was generated?

I want to echo something like this:
`Last update: {{ getDate }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You want `site.time`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#site-variables), which will show the exact date/time when the site was last generated:

```
2015-07-22 17:11:02 +0200
```

To output the exact date format you want, you can use [Liquid's date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7910554/6884).

For example, `{{ site.time | date: "%-d %B %Y"}}` will generate `22 July 2015`.