# Translating Jekyll dates

Tags: ruby, html, date, jekyll, datetime-format

I'm trying to translate my Jekyll dates to French.

I followed the advice on [this old reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32331857/7770081) on another StackOverflow question.

The idea is to create a **custom plugin** that:

1. translates the names of months to French, and
2. creates an html5-friendly date format for the `<time>` element.

Here's the code, copied from the other question and adapted from Italian: (`french_dates.rb` in my `_plugins` folder)

```
module Jekyll
module FrenchDates
    MONTHS = {"01" => "janvier", "02" => "février", "03" => "mars",
            "04" => "avril", "05" => "mai", "06" => "juin",
            "07" => "juillet", "08" => "août", "09" => "septembre",
            "10" => "octobre", "11" => "novembre", "12" => "décembre"}

    # http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html
    def frenchDate(date)
        day = time(date).strftime("%e") # leading zero is replaced by a space
        month = time(date).strftime("%m")
        year = time(date).strftime("%Y")
        day+' '+MONTHS[month]+' '+year
    end

    def html5date(date)
        day = time(date).strftime("%d")
        month = time(date).strftime("%m")
        year = time(date).strftime("%Y")
        year+'-'+month+'-'+day
    end
end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::FrenchDates)
```

And in Jekyll, call the plugin like this: (in my case in `_layouts/blog.html`)

`<time datetime="{{ page.date | html5date }}">{{ page.date | frenchDate }}</time>`

My problem is that when I try to implement this on my Jekyll site, I get the following error message:

`Liquid Exception: Invalid Date: 'nil' is not a valid datetime. in /_layouts/blog.html`

How can I make this plugin work?

Comment: Try adding `return "nil!" unless date` to the first line of each method. I suspect that one of your pages isn't passing the date somehow.

Comment: Thanks @Max, this made me look at where I was actually setting the date. It was never on the page, but on posts! So I had to slightly alter my code, and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

Even though I am editing a page, the date was set in the front matter of my *posts*.

Therefore this is how I have to call the plugin:

```
<time datetime="{{ post.date | html5date }}">{{ post.date | frenchDate }}</time>
```

My code was returning `nil` because the date is undefined on my page itself.